# Binary heap & minimum oriented priority queue's

Tags: queue, heap, binary-tree, priority-queue

could someone tell me which of these are binary heaps(max) and which of these are minimum oriented priority queue's, and why/why not that is? I'll post them in arrays since I don't know how to post pictures here, the x's mean that that position is blank.

Here we go: [8,6,7,4,6,6,x], [4,5,4,7,8,4,6],[,4,4,5,7,x,x,6]

I would assume that the first one is a binary heap, and the two others are minimum oriented priority queue´s, but according to the solutions I am wrong. The solutions might be wrong though, so please if you know which one is which please explain it to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first could be a binary max heap. That is, the tree would look like this:

```
          8
      6       7
    4   6   6
```

The second is a binary min heap:

```
          4
      5       4
    7   8   4   6
```

The third can't be a binary heap, because it doesn't conform to the shape property. That is, it would correspond to:

```
         4
     4       5
   7   x   x   6
```

In a binary heap, the bottom row is left-filled. This tree is not left-filled.

So the first is a binary max heap. The second is a binary min heap, which can also be viewed as a min-oriented priority queue. I don't know what to call the third one. It's not a valid min-heap, and it's not a sequential representation of a minimum priority queue, because 7 comes before 6.

At least, that's my answer based on my understanding of binary heaps and priority queues.